# Multiplication with category theory

Tags: category-theory

Using category theory why is 3*2=6?.

In book conceptual mathematics this is explained as :

[image]

So there are 3 object 6,3 & 2 with two maps , level & shadow.

There are 6 mapping from object 6 to object 2
There are 6 mapping from object 6 to object 3

6 is like a link object which joins the objects 3 and 2 ?

6 can be represented as . . . . . . or -> -> -> -> -> -> which both are representations of above diagrams . The -> represent the map or function between each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example we have two functions (=mapping) from the 6 element set, called '*level*' and '*shadow*': one maps onto the 2 element set (set of levels) and the other maps onto the 3 element set (set of shadows).

The arrows in the picture stand for the individual assignments.

It is not written here, but the categorical product $3\times 2$ means that this diagram of the two functions (level, shadow) is *universal* in the sense that any pair of functions $f:S\to 2$ and $g:S\to 3$ (for any set $S$) determine a unique function $S\to 3\times 2$ that yields $f$ when composed by 'level', and gives $g$ when composed by 'shadow'.

This property in general is satisfied by the set of all pairs from the given two sets.